# How can I see anonymous visitors in real time Google Analytics?

Tags: users, google-analytics

I can't see anonymous visitors in real-time in Google Analytics, I can only see
registered users. But I need see all visitors in Real-time>Overview , including anonymous visitors.

In the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module all roles are set.

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is not a Drupal Question, but anyways.
You can see Google Analytics for Anonymous users in your Google webmasters dashboard. Drupal has nothing to do with this.

Drupal Module for Google Analytics has only one function - Tell Google that it's your website and track its activities. Google does the real work of tracking.